# How to send handsontable with formula fields

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, handsontable

I have created handsontable with formula fields. When I save table, I got formulas in c# data table instead of formula result.
hear is my code to send table to C# webmethod:

```
var workTypeData = $.parseJSON(data.d[1]);
var container = document.getElementById('example');
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: workTypeData,
    rowHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: false,
    colHeaders: ['RoomDescriptionID', 'RoomDescriptionName', 'Area', 'Perimeter', 'Height'],
    columns: [
        { data: 'RoomDescriptionID' },
        { data: 'RoomDescriptionName' },
        { data: 'Area' },
        { data: 'Perimeter' },
        { data: 'Height' }
    ],
    formulas: true,
    manualColumnResize: true
});

var mydata = JSON.stringify(hot.getData());
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "FormulaBuilder.aspx/OnSave",
    data: "{ 'data' : '" + mydata + "' }",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d[0].length > 0) {
            alert("error in code");
        } else {
            
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, exception) {
        alert("error in ajax");
    }
});
```

And following is my c# webmethod:

```
var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(data);
```

I got data in json formate as shown below:

```
[{"RoomDescriptionID":1,"RoomDescriptionName":"Vestibule + Living + Dining","Area":"=SUM(D1:E1)","Perimeter":"=$E1/0.5","Height":0},{"RoomDescriptionID":2,"RoomDescriptionName":"Kitchen","Area":"=SUM(D2:E2)","Perimeter":"=$E2/0.5","Height":0},{"RoomDescriptionID":3,"RoomDescriptionName":"Area below Kitchen Platform","Area":"=SUM(D3:E3)","Perimeter":"=$E3/0.5","Height":0},{"RoomDescriptionID":4,"RoomDescriptionName":"Bed Room 1","Area":"=SUM(D4:E4)","Perimeter":"=$E4/0.5","Height":0},{"RoomDescriptionID":5,"RoomDescriptionName":"BR1 Toilet + Dress","Area":"=SUM(D5:E5)","Perimeter":"=$E5/0.5","Height":0},{"RoomDescriptionID":6,"RoomDescriptionName":"Bed Room 2","Area":"=SUM(D6:E6)","Perimeter":"=$E6/0.5","Height":0},{"RoomDescriptionID":7,"RoomDescriptionName":"BR2 Toilet + Dress","Area":"=SUM(D7:E7)","Perimeter":"=$E7/0.5","Height":0},{"RoomDescriptionID":8,"RoomDescriptionName":"Bed Room 3","Area":"=SUM(D8:E8)","Perimeter":"=$E8/0.5","Height":0},{"RoomDescriptionID":9,"RoomDescriptionName":"BR3 Toilet + Dress","Area":"=SUM(D9:E9)","Perimeter":"=$E9/0.5","Height":0}]
```

Here in Area it return formula instead of result

thank you.

Comment: welcome to SO! Please rephrase your question. It is not clear what do you want. Add more details of the code - like what is there in the variable hot and in what format does getData() return result with some example

Comment: hi siva, i have modify may question. hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't think this is related to [excel].  [handsontable] is excel-like, but not excel.

Comment: I have posted my problem with screenshots on github: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2468

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, but solved it with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074056/handsontable-save-formula-values).

Firstly you can use `hot.plugin.helper.cellValue('CELL REF')` to get the actual value, but when using getData() you're looking at the whole set. To solve this problem I basically iterated through the array replacing any formula cells with the value (I only needed columns up until 'K'):

```
var aCols = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K'];                   
var mydata = hot.getData();

for (i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < mydata[i].length; j++){
        if(mydata[i][j].toString().indexOf('=') > -1){
            mydata[i][j] = hot.plugin.helper.cellValue (aCols[j] + (i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Handsontable doesn't support formulas the way you are writing them. The comments are right in that Handsontable is 'excel-like' and not actually excel. This should have been an easy google search so I suggest you do a little bit of research before posting, however if you'd like this type of support, you have two options.

The first is to implement it yourself. The second is to use a third party library like [RuleJS](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable-ruleJS). The latter is probably what you're looking for.

EDIT:

It'll probably be useful for people looking for a way to add formula support so here is the solution.

The first step is to import the necessary CSS and JS source files for RuleJS. This can be done with the following (or download them to work offline):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/handsontable/handsontable.full.css">
<script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/RuleJS/js/ruleJS.js"></script>
<script src="http://handsontable.github.io/handsontable-ruleJS/lib/handsontable/handsontable.formula.js"></script>
```

The next step is to add the `formulas:true` option to your HOT instance. Now it should start working.

Comment: I have posted my problem on github with screenshots: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2468

Comment: If I put formula true, while invoking hot.getData() it is giving formula in array, how can I get actual value?